# Javascript execute code from a single tab

Tags: javascript, browser, pivot-table

The requirement is to execute the event listener on a single tab only. The event listener is an API which should be triggered through one tab when multiple browser tabs are opened. What is the best approach to do so?

Tried LocalStorage and StorageEvent but this seems to cause race condition

Comment: Use `postMessage()` to send messages between tabs?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "*The event listener is an API*" and how it is "*triggered*". If it's triggered by a dom event, just run the code in the tab where the event was fired?

Comment: You might be looking for a service worker or shared worker, both of which are singletons that can interact with multiple tabs.